# Flutter: I'm having this issue when running: flutter pub run builder_runner watch

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the error:

```
Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\internal\internal.dart:172:16 - This requires the 'non-nullable' 
language feature to be enabled.
[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on test/widget_test.dart:
```

This just happened after the last flutter upgrade. I've tried many solutions but nothing worked, even i reinstalled the flutter SDK.

This is the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
 sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  json_serializable: ^3.3.0
```

The test code:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'test.g.dart';

//@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
//@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
@JsonSerializable()
class Test{
  final String test;
  Test(this.test);
}
```

Comment: Try removing commented attributes. I'm not sure but I think it might affect build_runner compilation.

Comment: I've tried. No luck :(

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to solve this

- downgrade environment sdk to 2.1.0

like this

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: My solution was changing the flutter channel from master to stable, it worked for me :)

Comment: this is a good solution also
but when i made a new project it worked fine with me

Comment: Same problem and changing to beta channel also worked!

Comment: This does not work for me. I still get the error ` This requires the 'non-nullable' 
language feature to be enabled.` Any better idea?

Comment: Switching to stable is not working for us because we depend on some new features, and the beta branch is so unstable that many widgets that worked before show the red screen.